# I'm having an issue using set and get with session storage in React. I can see it being set but not getting. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, getter-setter, session-storage

I am currently working in React.

[This is where I am setting the information if I console.log in the browser I can see the correct data is being set. Ignore the setApiError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06f5v.png)

[This is where I am trying to get the information but user is never actually read.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxnNQ.png)

Comment: you just have to pass the key to the session to get as `const name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");` second argument is not required

Comment: try to wrap ur storage setters with JSON.stringify(value), it only takes json format

Comment: changing the input to just the key fixed the issue